# How to debug `locate` command?

Tags: unix, directory, find, locate

I have a directory call `mosesdecoder` in my home directory and when I try to `locate` it, it can't be found. The directory is newly created.

I have tried locating a previously created directory and the `locate` command works.

I have already tested the `locate` by creating a new directory and locating it but it doesn't locate the directory

```
alvas@ubi:~$ ls
examples.desktop
Templates
mosesdecoder
Desktop            
Documents          
Public                        
Videos
Downloads           
workspace
alvas@ubi:~$ locate 'mosesdecoder' | head -n1
alvas@ubi:~$ 
alvas@ubi:~$ locate 'workspace' | head -n1
/home/alvas/workspace
alvas@ubi:~$ locate 'Documents' | head -n1
/home/alvas/Documents
alvas@ubi:~$ mkdir testlocate
alvas@ubi:~$ locate 'testlocate'
alvas@ubi:~$
```

**Is there a reason why `locate` doesn't locate newly created directories?**

**Is there an index that the `locate` command searches from?**

**How do I debug the `locate` command?**

**What should I do such that newly created directories are "locate-able"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use updatedb to update the locate databases.

locate can "find" only the entries in the database, so it needs updating periodically.

Edit: more information about locate and locatedb and how it all works.
http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_locatedb.htm